# How to set default properties?

Tags: interface, shortcut, customization, workspaces

Let me explain by examples. I want the Mirror modifier always having Clipping ON, the object gizmos are being shown by default and so on. I know Blender is flexible and you can assign a shortcut for a lot of actions, but once again, I'd like to set default properties to save myself time. Is there a way to customize these parameters?

Answer (score 4):

I use this plugin https://github.com/Symstract/modifier_list, it has the ability to configure modifiers and their default values.

Any modifier can be pre-configured to the default value and when it is added, the parameters that you need will be there.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Set all these options in a new file, go to File > Defaults > Save Start-up File. Every new file you create will have these options set

Comment: Alright, that works just fine with many things, but in case of default Modifier properties that doesn't seemed to work unless I have a mesh with the modifier active. Any additional ideas?

Comment: @Garbuskna this technique really only works for parts of the user interface. I don't think you can change he defaults for modifiers without changing the C code.